# bayesian networks and data science

Tags: python, database, csv, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to build a bayesian network using Pyagrum in python, now when it comes to importing data, I have a csv file, i tried to use it as a database for my BN, however this message keeps showing:

```
MissingVariableInDatabase: [pyAgrum] Missing variable name in database: Variable 'Mois' is missing
```

'Mois' is the title of thefirst varaible in my database.

Comment: We need to see your code, otherwise it's impossible to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: [learner = gum.BNLearner('Donnees.csv',BN)  ] this is where I get the problem, BN is my bayesian network name, and Donnees is the name of the file containing my data, when I execute it i get the error message that i mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

it looks like in your BN, there is a variable "Mois" but not in your csv. Does it make sense ?
[image]

Comment: No!  it's the first variable in the database, I'm sure I checked out the csv file more than I can count...

Comment: Hi, I can not say more than that without your code and csv. It really lokks like column named 'Mois' is not found in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

*(I tried to add this as a comments to the last answer but formatting is not easy in comment so I add it as a new answer)*

You could try to create your learner without the bn

```py
learner = gum.BNLearner('Donnees.csv')
```

and look at the foudn variables in the csv:

```py
print(learner.names())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful, actually I had two problems, the first one is that the pyagrum didnt accept a name for the first variable and I don't know y, that's where your idea somehow helped me, the second one wasin my csv file, the values are seperated by this (;) instead of this (,), because I use the french system, I replaced them and I managed to solve the problem. Thank you Again

Comment: Nice. But as far as I know, pyAgrum do accept a name for the first variable... aGrUM (C++) allows you to change the separator in CSV file but not the 
wrapped version in pyAgrum (at least for now).

Comment: Yeah maybe the problem is in my csv file, but it's not a big problem at least I was able to finish the work, thank you very much for helping me